# OS X Lion crashes on print

Tags: macos, mac, printing

Any time I try and print any file from any application, the application trying to print crashes with this error:

> sandbox.d deny file-write-create /Library/Caches/Canon/UFR2

Sandbox seems to be preventing any app from printing while my Canon 28080-380i printer.

I am going to reinstall OS X, but any help would be greatly appreciated.

Here is the full error log:

```
TextEdit(1081) deny file-write-create /Library/Caches/Canon/UFR2

Process:         TextEdit [1081]
Path:            /Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit
Load Address:    0x10241d000
Identifier:      TextEdit
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       X86-64 (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [171]

Date/Time:       2011-08-15 23:47:10.325 -0700
OS Version:      Mac OS X 10.7 (11A511)
Report Version:  7

Backtrace:
0   libsystem_kernel.dylib          0x00007fff84fdd8ea mkdir + 10
1   libinfo.dylib                   0x00000001069a9909 zMakeCashFileFolder + 251
2   libinfo.dylib                   0x00000001069aa318 Info_Initialize + 168
3   PDEUtilities                    0x000000010694f69e Info_Initialize + 171
4   PDEUtilities                    0x000000010691c845 -[MCDUFR2CNPDEBidiController initInfoLibrary:::] + 26
5   PDEUtilities                    0x000000010691c785 -[MCDUFR2CNPDEBidiController initWithBundle:::] + 316
6   PDEUtilities                    0x000000010692c793 -[MCDUFR2PDEPanelCommon initWithCallback:bundle:funcList:] + 322
7   FinishingPDE                    0x00000001068c01a8 -[MCDUFR2FinishingPDE initWithCallback::] + 60
8   FinishingPDE                    0x00000001068d20c2 -[MCDUFR2FinishingPDEPlugIn PDEPanelsForType:withHostInfo:] + 176
9   PrintCocoaUI                    0x0000000106809f82
10  PrintCocoaUI                    0x000000010680b30e
11  PrintCocoaUI                    0x000000010680b7c2
12  PrintCocoaUI                    0x000000010680e7b1
13  PrintCocoaUI                    0x0000000106821f07
14  PrintCocoaUI                    0x00000001068226b4
15  AppKit                          0x00007fff8e4ffa23 -[NSWindowController _windowDidLoad] + 566
16  AppKit                          0x00007fff8e4f7105 -[NSWindowController window] + 109
17  AppKit                          0x00007fff8e80bcf5 -[NSPrintPanel beginSheetWithPrintInfo:modalForWindow:delegate:didEndSelector:contextInfo:] + 606
18  AppKit                          0x00007fff8e808695 -[NSConcretePrintOperation runOperationModalForWindow:delegate:didRunSelector:contextInfo:] + 477
19  AppKit                          0x00007fff8e6a9602 __-[NSDocument runModalPrintOperation:delegate:didRunSelector:contextInfo:]_block_invoke_1 + 228
20  AppKit                          0x00007fff8e6b94b6 -[NSDocument performActivityWithSynchronousWaiting:usingBlock:] + 82
21  AppKit                          0x00007fff8e6a9518 -[NSDocument runModalPrintOperation:delegate:didRunSelector:contextInfo:] + 96
22  AppKit                          0x00007fff8e6a9319 __-[NSDocument printDocumentWithSettings:showPrintPanel:delegate:didPrintSelector:contextInfo:]_block_invoke_4 + 142
23  AppKit                          0x00007fff8e69d823 -[NSDocument continueActivityUsingBlock:] + 42
24  AppKit                          0x00007fff8e6a8f45 __-[NSDocument printDocumentWithSettings:showPrintPanel:delegate:didPrintSelector:contextInfo:]_block_invoke_3 + 250
25  AppKit                          0x00007fff8e6a8d93 __-[NSDocument printDocumentWithSettings:showPrintPanel:delegate:didPrintSelector:contextInfo:]_block_invoke_2 + 1097
26  AppKit                          0x00007fff8e6b05e0 -[NSDocument _commitEditingThenContinue:] + 337
27  AppKit                          0x00007fff8e6ac2ab -[NSDocument _commitEditingWithDelegate:didSomethingSelector:contextInfo:thenContinue:] + 91
28  AppKit                          0x00007fff8e6a88bf __-[NSDocument printDocumentWithSettings:showPrintPanel:delegate:didPrintSelector:contextInfo:]_block_invoke_1 + 232
29  AppKit                          0x00007fff8e6b9670 -[NSDocument performActivityWithSynchronousWaiting:usingBlock:] + 524
30  AppKit                          0x00007fff8e6a87d1 -[NSDocument printDocumentWithSettings:showPrintPanel:delegate:didPrintSelector:contextInfo:] + 103
31  AppKit                          0x00007fff8e6a8763 -[NSDocument printDocument:] + 70
32  CoreFoundation                  0x00007fff8ef8511d -[NSObject performSelector:withObject:] + 61
33  AppKit                          0x00007fff8e406852 -[NSApplication sendAction:to:from:] + 139
34  AppKit                          0x00007fff8e4f334f -[NSMenuItem _corePerformAction] + 399
35  AppKit                          0x00007fff8e4f3086 -[NSCarbonMenuImpl performActionWithHighlightingForItemAtIndex:] + 125
36  AppKit                          0x00007fff8e4707e3 -[NSMenu performKeyEquivalent:] + 281
37  AppKit                          0x00007fff8e46f439 -[NSApplication _handleKeyEquivalent:] + 526
38  AppKit                          0x00007fff8e3679fa -[NSApplication sendEvent:] + 4354
39  AppKit                          0x00007fff8e2fe42b -[NSApplication run] + 548
40  AppKit                          0x00007fff8e57c52a NSApplicationMain + 867
41  TextEdit                        0x000000010241ee38

Binary Images:
       0x10241d000 -        0x10243aff7  com.apple.TextEdit (1.7 - 288) <53AD47DC-BF82-36C5-8CA0-A03C55390F74> /Applications/TextEdit.app/Contents/MacOS/TextEdit
       0x106803000 -        0x10683afff  com.apple.print.framework.Print.Private (7.0 - 378) <9EECB9C5-32C3-3CBE-8D9A-82E929A7D69A> /System/Library/PrivateFrameworks/PrintingPrivate.framework/Versions/Current/Plugins/PrintCocoaUI.bundle/Contents/MacOS/PrintCocoaUI
       0x1068bf000 -        0x1068e5fff +jp.co.canon.MCDUFR2.PDEs.Finishing (2.25 - 2.25) <9FA0CE6E-4D2E-8FE7-0884-83754A03DE22> /Library/Printers/Canon/UFR2/PDEs/FinishingPDE.plugin/Contents/MacOS/FinishingPDE
       0x10691b000 -        0x106965fff +jp.co.canon.MCDUFR2.PDEUtilities (2.25 - 2.25) <75767673-8F8D-E59F-09DE-5337B5C9B296> /Library/Printers/Canon/UFR2/Frameworks/PDEUtilities.framework/Versions/A/PDEUtilities
       0x1069a9000 -        0x1069b1fff +libinfo.dylib (1.0.1 - compatibility 1.0.0) <63BDED2F-7725-2B77-1019-E872A5F228FA> /Library/Printers/Canon/UFR2/Libs/libinfo.dylib
    0x7fff84fc6000 -     0x7fff84fe6fff  libsystem_kernel.dylib (1699.22.73 - compatibility 1.0.0) <69F2F501-72D8-3B3B-8357-F4418B3E1348> /usr/lib/system/libsystem_kernel.dylib
    0x7fff8e2f9000 -     0x7fff8eef1fff  com.apple.AppKit (6.7 - 1138) <C8D2FDDA-B9D5-3948-A376-6B9B6F0596C6> /System/Library/Frameworks/AppKit.framework/Versions/C/AppKit
    0x7fff8eef2000 -     0x7fff8f0c5ff7  com.apple.CoreFoundation (6.7 - 635) <57446B22-0778-3E07-9690-96AC705D57E8> /System/Library/Frameworks/CoreFoundation.framework/Versions/A/CoreFoundation
```

Comment: This is also a problem I am experiencing in OSX Lion Server 10.7.2 (fresh install)

Comment: Figure it out yet?

Comment: Does the problem still occur?

Comment: Reinstalling took care of it...